# Get components names from JPanel, failing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

What could be the problem here why the static method doesn't print components names of components in a JPanel?

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Window;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Users {
    public static void saveUpdate(JPanel pnlUsers)
    {           
        Component[] components = pnlUsers.getComponents();

        for(int i=0;i<components.length;i++){
             System.out.println("Component name - " + components[i].getName());  
             // For database update. Code will be added after fix.
        }
    }
}
```

`components[i].getName()` always returns null instead of the componenet's name.

Comment: components[i].getName() always returns null instead of the componenet's name.

Comment: Well what type of names do you hope to see? JLabel, JPanel, etc or the variable name?

Comment: like the name of a JTextField like txtFirstName

Comment: variable name of component

Comment: you need to typecast Components into JTextField etc. to get the text of the field using getText().

Comment: That works in getting the texts and setting them. But I need to also know variable names of JTextField components.

Comment: Right now, getting the variable name just returns null in components[i].getName()

Comment: Fixed it already. Had to do setName("") call on its components first for getName() to not return null.

Comment: If you want to get a specific name for a particular component then you will need to use the **setName()** property for that component and give it a specific name (like "myJTextField"). I don't believe you can actually get an actual variable name of a component and even if you could you need to realize that it's possible for several variables to point to the same object instance. You can however easily get a Class Name.

Comment: See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) It is likely that this problem would better be approached in an entirely different way. E.G. by keeping a model that is used to update the state of the GUI components.

Comment: Sorry. It's actually for saving update to database from the components contained in the panel. Updated the posted code anyways :)

Comment: Tip: Add @DevilsHnd (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Ok, got it. Thanks :)